# Prestashop add customer method

Tags: php, prestashop

I have a piece of code like this in init() method of class extending ModuleFrontController, but it doesn't work and i don't know why. I've checked definition in Customer class and only names, email and passwd is required, but nothing is happened in database. Prestashop 1.5.6.1

```
$customer = new Customer();
$customer->firstname = 'name';
$customer->lastname = 'lastname';
$customer->email = 'mail@mail.com';
$customer->passwd = md5(time());
$customer->is_guest = 1;

$customer->add();
```

EDIT: This code works in postProcess() method in same class, so what is wrong..?

Answer (score 1):

If you are placing the code under init() method - you are overriding the default init.

Try to call first the parent init and then add your code:

```
public function init()
{ 
    parent::init(); 
    ...
```